# Data List Support Model Binding Asp.Net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datalist

Does the DataList Control in ASp.net 4.5 support Strongly typed Model Binding? I think of the DataList control as a 'Data Control' and in asp.net 4.5 the data controls support the ItemType attribute and the SelectMethod attribute in order to allow strong typing.
But in my DataList control I get no compile error yet the SelectMethod is never called.
Despite some examples on the net in my searches (didn't find anything on SO)
(e.g. www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/aspnet45features.aspx probably an untested example) it seems the DataList Control does not inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl like GridView does. 
GridView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx
DataList: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx
So I get no compile error when using ItemType and no call to SelectMethod. Apparently it's just not supported.
Am I missing something? What other 'Data' Controls do NOT support Strong Typing?

Comment: All this because I tried to use the obsoleted control (FLAF) (Feel like a fool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are completely right (so feel free to go ahead and accept your own answer, since you already did all the required research) - and as an intended workaround, use it's replacement control instead, the `ListView` (like all other replaced things, the `DataList` is still supported solely for backward compatibility, but not updated anymore in any other way)

And all other data-bound controls DO support the strongly typed model binding (even the `DropDownList`, and it's like).